# Load balancing of process load balancer

Tags: nginx

I have a loadbalancer named LB1, which balance between my 2 ip when it receive a request on *.domain.com. I have put a max_fails and a fail_timeout in order to redirect trafic on the other when one is down :

```
upstream upstreamdomain {

   least_conn;


   server X.X.X.1 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=10s;
   server X.X.X.2 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=10s;

 }


server {

    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.domain.com;



    location / {

        proxy_set_header Host $subdomain.domain.com;

        proxy_pass http://upstreamdomain;

    }

}
```

On each X.X.X.1 and X.X.X.2 i have my applications running on Y process, and i manage the loadbalancing between process with nginx too

```
upstream defaultupstream {
    least_conn;


    server 127.0.0.1:9000 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=10s;
    server 127.0.0.1:9001 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=10s;
    server 127.0.0.1:9002 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=10s;
 }
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.domain.com;



    location / {
       proxy_set_header Host $subdomain.domain.com;
       proxy_pass http://defaultupstream;
    }
 }
```

When a server is crashing down i want that LB1 redirect trafic on the other, and **it works well**.

When a process is crashing on X.X.X.1 or X.X.X.2 i want that nginx redirect trafic on other process, and **it works well**.

The problem i have its when all process are crashing on X.X.X.1 or X.X.X.2 the nginx on X.X.X.1 or X.X.X.2 return 502 server unavailable

It seems that the 502 response not increasing the max_fails on LB1, LB1 is still considering the server with no working process as alive.

**How can i configure nginx on LB1 in order to eval 502 as a fail ?
If its not possible, on X.X.X.1 and X.X.X.2 what i have to repond (503, 504 . ?) in order that my LB1 consider the server as down ?**

**---------------------- EDIT ------------------**

Thanks to **oklas**, fix by adding the following line in LB1 configuration, in order to force nginx to change the upstream on error, timeout or http 502, 503 and 504:

```
proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_502 http_503 http_504;
```

LB1 conf is now :

```
upstream upstreamdomain {

   least_conn;


   server X.X.X.1 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=10s;
   server X.X.X.2 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=10s;

 }


server {

    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.domain.com;



    location / {

        proxy_set_header Host $subdomain.domain.com;

        proxy_pass http://upstreamdomain;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_502 http_503 http_504;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify directive which declare conditions to switch to another server in your frontend server:

```
proxy_next_upstream http_502;
```

---

Also take into account relaited things:

- to replace error code with another

```
error_page 404 =200 /.nop.html;
```

- close current connection by condition

```
if (condition) {
   return 444;
}
```

where `444` is nginx special error code mean `close current connection`